# How can I show the date in the format of date9 in this SQL process?

Tags: sas

After I run this SAS SQL process. The date variable "EXVISDAT" showed in the results in a numerical way. How can I change the code to let the date variable "EXVISDAT" show in format of "date9."？

```
proc sql;
    create table test2 as
    select VISIT, Targetdays, Targetdays + '01JUL2019'd - 1 as EXVISDAT
    from data_in.chrono_visits_lts14424
    order by Targetdays
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: Did you try to use format?

Comment: `Targetdays + '01JUL2019'd - 1 as EXVISDAT format=date9.` , try this:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about it in [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473684.htm).

In yours case, query will look like:

```
proc sql;
    create table test2 as
    select VISIT, Targetdays, Targetdays + '01JUL2019'd - 1 as EXVISDAT format=date9.
    from data_in.chrono_visits_lts14424
    order by Targetdays
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: This really helped a lot! Thank you~